# Extracting parts of HTML from website using python

Tags: python, html

I'm currently working on a project that involves a program to inspect a web page's HTML using Python. My program has to monitor a web page, and when a change is made to the HTML, it will complete a set of actions. My question is how do you extract just part of a web page, and how do you monitor a web page's HTML and report almost instantly when a change is made. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the past I wrote my own parsers. Nowadays HTML is HTML 5, more statements,more Javascript, a lot of crappiness done by developers and their editors, like

```
document.write('<SCR' + 'IPT
```

And some web frameworks / developers bad coding change the Last-Modified in the HTTP header on every request, even if for a human person the text you read on the page isn't changed.

I suggest you [BeautifulSoup](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html) for the parsing stuff; by your own you have to careful choose what to watch to decide if the Web page is modified.

Its intro :

> BeautifulSoup is a Python package that parses broken HTML, just like
>   lxml supports it based on the parser of libxml2. BeautifulSoup uses a
>   different parsing approach. It is not a real HTML parser but uses
>   regular expressions to dive through tag soup. It is therefore more
>   forgiving in some cases and less good in others. It is not uncommon
>   that lxml/libxml2 parses and fixes broken HTML better, but
>   BeautifulSoup has superiour support for encoding detection. It very
>   much depends on the input which parser works better.

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy might be a good place to start.  http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html

Getting sections of websites is easy, it is just xml, you can use scrapy or beautifulsoup.